# What i need to add in query so it only display prior week data and add a selector in ssrs report to be able to go back in time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE
     @startdate DATETIME,
     @enddate DATETIME

SET @enddate = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, getdate()), -1) 
SET @startdate = DATEADD(wk, -1, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0,getdate()), -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-parameters-report-builder-and-report-designer?view=sql-server-2017) with default values for the prior week. Users will be able to change the dates to be able to get a selected date range.

The Start Date default value would be something like

```
=TODAY.AddDays(1 - TODAY.DayOfWeek - 7)
```

and the End Date default would be

```
=TODAY.AddDays(0 - TODAY.DayOfWeek)
```

Then you use the parameter in your dataset's query. If you use the same name, the parameter will automatically mapped in the Parameter tab of the dataset.

Comment: as you can see in the body of my question i already have the date parameters for prior week with a declare statement: (DECLARE
 @ startdate datetime
,@ enddate datetime
SET @ enddate = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, getdate()), -1) 
SET @ startdate = DATEADD(wk, -1, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0,getdate()), -1));and setting them up in the where clause of the query. (WHERE
    DateShipped >= @  startdate AND DateShipped <  @ enddate  ) My question is that this will only display prior week results. I need and addition of a date selector to be able to go back in time months or years

Comment: @Jose - yes, I see your dates in your query but if you leave your dates hard-coded in your query, the user won't be able to select any different parameters. The date parameter will default the date range to the prior week but lets users have the ability change it to any date range.